# 'INFO: Could not find files for the given patterns' Error I receive using pdfkit

Tags: python, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I convert .csv file to HTML and then try to convert HTML to PDF using pdfkit...   What am I doing wrong.  How do I fix this.  Here is my code snippet below.

```py
import pdfkit

# put unsafe operation in try block
try:
    print("code start")

    # unsafe operation perform
    # wkhtmltopdf = WKHtmlToPdf(url='pypi.org', output_file='new.pdf')
    pdfkit.from_file('myhtml.html', 'mypdf.pdf')
    # pdfkit.from_url('https://www.google.com/', 'mypdf.pdf')
    print(1 / 4)

# if error occur the it goes in except block
except:
    print("an error occurs")

# final code in finally block
finally:
    print("StackOverFlow")
```

I do not have wkhtmltopdf imported, is that a mistake

Comment: Please make your code readable without huge and bold fonts. Also, you print a senseless message `an error occurs`, you should print an exception that occured instead,

Answer (score 0):

Install the GTK runtime from this link: https://github.com/tschoonj/GTK-for-Windows-Runtime-Environment-Installer/releases

Then in your code add:
import os
os.add_dll_directory(r"C:\Program Files\GTK3-Runtime Win64\bin")